# Enrich-My-Library For all Traversables

Tags: scala, types, implicit, enrich-my-library

I was trying to figure out how to write a functional swap function that works on any `Traversable[_]`, given a collection and the indexes to swap. I came up with the following:

```
def swap[A, CC <% Traversable[A]](xs: CC, i: Int, j: Int): Traversable[A] = {
  xs.slice(0, i) ++ 
    xs.slice(j, j+1) ++ 
    xs.slice(i+1, j) ++ 
    xs.slice(i, i+1) ++ 
    xs.slice(j+1, xs.size)
}

swap(List(1,2,3,4,5), 0, 4) // => List(5,2,3,4,1)
```

I'd like to know how to make this into an implicit extension of Traversable, enabling me to call it with `List(1,2,3,4,5).swap(0, 4)`. The closest I could get was the following:

```
import language.implicitConversions
class RichTraversable[A, B <% Traversable[A]](xs: B) {
  def swap(i: Int, j: Int): Traversable[A] = {
    xs.slice(0, i) ++ 
      xs.slice(j, j+1) ++ 
      xs.slice(i+1, j) ++ 
      xs.slice(i, i+1) ++ 
      xs.slice(j+1, xs.size)
  }
} 
implicit def richTraversable[A, B <% Traversable[A]](ys: B)(implicit b: Traversable[A])
  = new RichTraversable[A, B](ys)
```

Unfortunately that's not quite it. Calling `List(1,2,3,4,5).swap(0, 4)` results in the following error:

> error: No implicit view available from List[Int] => Traversable[A]

I feel I must be missing something, or vastly over-complicating the issue. Does anyone know how this should be structured?

---

*Note: This is purely academic, and not being used in a production environment in any way. I'm trying to get a better handle on Scala's type system and bounds.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Scala 2.10:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.TraversableLike

implicit class TraversableWithSwap[A, Repr <: Traversable[A]](val xs: TraversableLike[A, Repr]) extends AnyVal {
  def swap[That](i: Int, j: Int)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, That]): That = {
    val builder = bf(xs.asInstanceOf[Repr])
    builder.sizeHint(xs)
    builder ++= xs.take(i)
    builder ++= xs.slice(j, j + 1)
    builder ++= xs.slice(i + 1, j)
    builder ++= xs.slice(i, i + 1)
    builder ++= xs.drop(j + 1)
    builder.result
  }
}
```

(The `AnyVal` thing turns it into a Value Class, meaning that the compiler will rewrite it as a static function to avoid actually doing the wrapping during runtime.)

If using an earlier version, drop the `extends AnyVal` and use an implicit-conversion function instead of `implicit class`:

```
implicit def toTraversableWithSwap[A, Repr <: Traversable[A]](xs: TraversableLike[A, Repr]) = new TraversableWithSwap(xs)
```

And using it:

```
scala> Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).swap(2,5)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8, 9)
```

Note that it doesn't actually make sense to define this function for all `Traversable` since some traversables (like `Set`, `Map`, etc) are unordered, so swapping two elements is meaningless.  You probably would actually want to define it for all `Seq` or something.

*Also:* Can we also just agree to call it "enhance-my-library" already?

Comment: First: Woah, what's this builder I've never seen before? And Second: Yes, we can agree to call it that from now on =)

Comment: The builder is what is used in the internal collections.  See, for example: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L237

Comment: Hmm. I can't get it to find CanBuildFrom or TraversableLike. Is there an import I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to import those.  See my edit.  By the way: if you need to locate a class to import, you can always find it in the API: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html.

Comment: Thanks. I did check out the API, but I somehow missed the line at the very top with the right package. I'd +1 you again, but alas, I cannot.